# Unable to deploy ear application through maven script

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, maven-3, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy an ear application from through Maven scrip in Eclipse IDE. From WebLogic 12c Console, the same application is getting deployed and running well. However I am trying to deploy thorugh Mav Script, I am getting the following exception.
Below is POM.xml and exception:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for root.project:ear:ear:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin is missing. @ line 27, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ear assembly 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ ear ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\eclipse-jee-kepler\workspace\project\ear\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.6:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) @ ear ---
[INFO] Generating application.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ ear ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\eclipse-jee-kepler\workspace\project\ear\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.6:ear (default-ear) @ ear ---
[INFO] Copying artifact[war:com.hcl:ejb-web-client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] to[ejb-web-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
[INFO] Copying artifact[jar:com.hcl:EJBServerForSpring:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] to[EJBServerForSpring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]
[INFO] Could not find manifest file: C:\eclipse-jee-kepler\workspace\project\ear\target\ear-1.0\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF - Generating one
[INFO] Building jar: C:\eclipse-jee-kepler\workspace\project\ear\target\ear-1.0.ear
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- weblogic-maven-plugin:12.1.3.0:deploy (wl-deploy) @ ear ---
The args for the deployer is: -noexit -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -password ******** -deploy -source ../ear/target/ear-1.0.ear -targets AdminServer -upload -verbose 
weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -noexit -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -deploy -source ../ear/target/ear-1.0.ear -targets AdminServer -upload -verbose
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.553s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 14 01:50:47 EST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:12.1.3.0:deploy (wl-deploy) on project ear: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 'http://localhost:7001': weblogic.security.utils.KeyStoreConfiguration. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:12.1.3.0:deploy (wl-deploy) on project ear: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 'http://localhost:7001': weblogic.security.utils.KeyStoreConfiguration. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 'http://localhost:7001': weblogic.security.utils.KeyStoreConfiguration. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server.
    at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
```

**Pom.xml file:**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
                <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>12.1.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <adminurl>http://localhost:7001</adminurl>
                    <user>weblogic</user>
                    <password>weblogic1</password>
                    <upload>true</upload>
                    <targets>AdminServer</targets>
                    <action>deploy</action>
                    <remote>false</remote>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>../ear/target/ear-1.0.ear</source>
                    <!-- <name>${project.build.finalName}</name> -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution> -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>wl-deploy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>deploy</goal> 
                        </goals> 
                    </execution>
                </executions>


            </plugin>
```

The tunning is also enable for the server. Server is up and running.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Go to Administration Console at Environment > Servers > AdminServer > Protocols > HTTP and set Enable Tunneling= true

Comment: @KennethClark I already did the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is located based on this:

> Unable to connect to 'http://localhost:7001':
>   weblogic.security.utils.KeyStoreConfiguration. Ensure the url
>   represents a running admin server and that the credentials are
>   correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the
>   admin serve

Comment: @khmarbiase I tried with t3:// also, but it was having the same exception.

Comment: Have you tried to use `t3s://`? Keystore is configured correct?

Comment: How to configure KeyStore. I tried t3::// also but the same error is coming up.